# Identical method in two projects having different performances

Tags: c#

I have an issue with seemingly identical C# code benchmarking differently in two projects.

The code is a C# implementation of the Winding Number Algorithm to find out whether a point is inside of a polygon.

The List is an ordered list of Vertexes which have a Latitude & Longitude. When you draw a line from each vertex, in order, you trace out a polygon, and the method determines whether or not the point is inside of the polygon.

Here is the code:

```
public static bool IsPointInPolygon(List<Vertex> polygon, Vertex point)
{
    int wn = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (polygon.Count - 1); i++)
    {
        if (polygon[i].Latitude <= point.Latitude)
        {
            if (polygon[i + 1].Latitude > point.Latitude)
            {
                if (IsLeft(polygon[i], polygon[i + 1], point) > 0)
                    wn++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (polygon[i + 1].Latitude <= point.Latitude)
            {
                if (IsLeft(polygon[i], polygon[i + 1], point) < 0)
                    wn--;
            }
        }
    }
    return wn != 0;
}

private static double IsLeft(Vertex lineStart, Vertex lineEnd, Vertex point)
{
    return ((lineEnd.Longitude - lineStart.Longitude) * (point.Latitude - lineStart.Latitude)
         - (point.Longitude - lineStart.Longitude) * (lineEnd.Latitude - lineStart.Latitude));
}
```

Here is my Vertex class:

```
public class Vertex
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public Vertex(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        this.Latitude = latitude;
        this.Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Vertex(double latitude, double longitude, int order)
    {
        this.Latitude = latitude;
        this.Longitude = longitude;
        this.Order = order;
    }
}
```

Here is the code I am using in both projects to benchmark (I'm using a concurrent bag because I'm processing in parallel, inside the "*****"):

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<double> times = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<double>();
// *****
// *****
var start = DateTime.Now;
bool isPointInPoly = IsPointInPolygon(poly, point); // where poly is a List<Vertex> and point is a Vertex
var end = DateTime.Now;
times.Add((end - start).TotalMilliseconds);
// *****
// *****
Debug.WriteLine(times.Average());
```

In one solution, the average time I get returned is approximately 0.007 ms, but in another it's about double that at 0.014 ms.

In both solutions, I am passing an identical data set, with both the List being in the same order, and the entire method (which is called numerous times) being called in the same order.

Both my solutions have been compared in "Debug" and "Release", and both have been compared with the "Optimise Code" flag set, with the same ratio of perfomance difference in all tests.

Can you suggest any other settings/code issues that I could tweak/investigate in order to find out the reason for the performance difference? Also, if you need any more information, let me know and I'll provide it.

**Update:**
I ran the Visual Studio performance analysis on both projects. Here is the slow version:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiG4Z.png

And here is the quick version:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Peel8.png

Apologies that I can't hyperlink the images directly, I don't have 10 reputation yet.

Answer (score 5):

When you benchmark performance, **don't use** `DateTime.Now` to track the elapsed time. Instead, use the [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, which is built for that purpose and much more precise:

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// Execute code

stopwatch.Stop();
long duration = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

You should also measure **many executions** of the same code rather than just a single one. Very short execution times are hard to measure exactly. Consider running your code a million times and compare those values.

Comment: Thanks for replying Marius. I have changed the timer to this but the result is identical. Further, I have very approximately timed the process running 5000 * 2350, which is just under 12 million times, with the time being approximately 20 seconds in one project and 40 seconds in another.
Further, the performance difference is obvious when running it across my entire dataset, so I don't think the issue is with the timer itself.

Comment: @Hy Optimization is a form of black magic. Many books are written about it, many people ask lots of money for doing it, sometimes with worse outcomes.
Your written code is just the first step in the Optimization progress. And it mostly boils down about how data is accessed and stored. You might know that your polygon data sets does not change before and during your tests. but your compiler might not. And in one of your projects the compiler might be copying the dataset many times over. because it cannot guarantee a different thread is updating the data. A library might over constant speed